# Comparing the data attribute value of 2 arrays and checking the innerHTML of the selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using Vanilla JS and PHP. I have a series of checkboxes for blog posts. Each post has its own associated checkbox and on each checkbox there is a `value` which is the equivalent of the `postID` from the mysql db. I have a foreach checking the checkboxes to see which one is clicked and then it pushes that value onto an empty array.

I also have a 2nd array that is filled with the posts id using a separate data attribute as the elements are not on the same DOM level. The 2nd array values contain a status within a `<span>` that either say 'Published' or 'Draft'. The `span` has its own `data-` attribute identifying the post id. I want to compare ids from both arrays and check the `innerHTML` of the `span` belonging to the 2nd array. Right now I have a check in place but it only checks the first value int the 2nd array.

Checkbox foreach

```
//Store post id from checkbox
    let checkBox = document.querySelectorAll('.postCheckBox');
    let postIDs = [];
    let blogIDs = [];


    checkBox.forEach(function (element) {
        if (element.checked) {
            //Store POST ids
            postIDs.push(element.value);
            //Store BLOG ids
            blogIDs.push(element.dataset.blog);
        }
    });
```

and in the dom it looks like (the value is the postID)

```
<input type="checkbox" class="postCheckBox" value="5" data-blog="1">
```

My 2nd array with values

```
let customPostIds = [];

 Array.prototype.slice.call(postStatus).forEach(post => {
        customPostIds.push(post);
    })

    console.log(customPostIds)
```

which when consoled returns

[image: Returned from console.log(customPostIds)]

And in each of those elements I do see `dataset` and the `innerHTML` just not sure how to use it to compare it to the first array AND extract the `innerHTML` to do a check.

[image: Inside of the first element]

If you need more info to give feedback let me know so I can add whatever info is needed.

The end result I am hoping to achieve is to have a valid `if` statement check. Pseudo code:

```
if((postID.id === customPostIds.id) && customPostIds.innerHTML === 'Draft') {return true;}
```

The tricky part is that `customPostIds` needs 2 values extracted from it... 1) The `data-post-id` and the `innerHTML` from each item in the array. However, the `dataset.postId` and the `innerHTML` from the `customPostIds` array which I want to extract, do not live on the same HTML element in the DOM.

Comment: what you need exactly? tag the ids in the first array with "published" or "draft", with information taken from second list?

Comment: @brunoff I want to compare if array1.id  === array2.id AND array2[i].innerHTML === “Draft” all in an if statement and if both are true then just return. The tricky part is that the innerHTML only lives on the same element from what is returned in array2